# Is setting up XSRF-TOKEN on the server still required with HttpClientXsrfModule?

Tags: javascript, angular, express, csrf, nestjs

Is it enough to simply write the following code in order to prevent XSRF/CSRF in **app.module** on the client side?

```
HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
  cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
  headerName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'
})
```

Or is some extra logic on the server (Express/NestJS) still required?

Answer (score 4):

Your server needs to implement csrf tokens. The client then sends the token back so that it can be checked on your server. For more information see [understanding csrf tokens](https://github.com/pillarjs/understanding-csrf#csrf-tokens).

---

To add csrf support to your nestjs application you can use the [csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) middleware, see [nest security docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/security#csrf):

First install csurf:

```
$ npm i --save csurf
```

Then add the middleware in your main.ts

```
import * as csurf from 'csurf';
app.use(csurf());
```

Comment: These 2 lines this is all for a trivial case? No need to pass the CSRF token on the server like this example https://github.com/expressjs/csurf#single-page-application-spa ?

Comment: No, you need to follow the instructions. It won't work without adding a session or cookie parser etc.

Comment: Looks like express-session is enough, as since 1.5.0 cookire-parses middleware no longer needs to be used with express-session according to the official documentaiton. Thus it looks, like these 2 lines with **HttpClientXsrfModule** + these 2 lines with **csurf** + **express-session**.